# c++ vector of strings, erasing characters act weird

Tags: c++, substring, erase

I'm trying to write my own json parser for my data. A single entry looks like this when cut

```
`"ID":"612","path":"letter_2013-12-16 17:49:43  0000.png","longitude":"24.9767","latitude":"60.2099","letter":"K"`
```

now I'm trying to put these into another vector where I cut out the individual data needed. As I didn't find a way to delete " from a string in c++ (suggestions welcome) I am going about it as follows:

```
individualEntries=ofSplitString(fullResponse, "},{");
for(int i=0; i<individualEntries.size(); i++){
    printf("entry %s \n",individualEntries[i].c_str());
    vector<string> cutEntries =ofSplitString(individualEntries[i], ",");
    for(int j=0; j<cutEntries.size(); j++){
        //delete "ID":"
        cutEntries[0].erase (0, 6);
        //delete "
        cutEntries[0]=cutEntries[0].substr(0,cutEntries[0].length()-1);

        //delete "path":"
        cutEntries[1].erase(0,4);
        cutEntries[1]=cutEntries[1].substr(0,cutEntries[1].length()-1);
        //cutEntries[1].append("g");
        printf("%s ",cutEntries[j].c_str());
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

and it results in this:

```
1159 letter_2014-01-19 12:59:05  0000.pn "longitude":"25.0903" "latitude":"60.1956" "letter":"I"
```

it works fine for the first part, I cut out nicely my IDs, but then when trying to cut out the "path":" it starts acting weird. The length should be of length 8, but cutting out 4 achieves the right goal. And when doing the substring to delete the last letter, it deletes the last 2. It's strange that the same doesn't happen to the first entry (cutEntries[0]) but only to the second (cutEntries[1]). Any ideas?

Comment: Something like a combination of [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) and [`std::istream::ignore`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore), properly utilized, will likely make parsing the initial input considerably more robust.

Comment: can u show how to use it in this case?

Comment: The samples are cppreference.com in the provided links should suffice as a general usage guide. Thats why they're provided with the documentation.

Comment: sorry, no they don't...

Answer (score 0):

This loop

```
for(int j=0; j<cutEntries.size(); j++){
    //delete "ID":"
    cutEntries[0].erase (0, 6);
    //delete "
    cutEntries[0]=cutEntries[0].substr(0,cutEntries[0].length()-1);

    //delete "path":"
    cutEntries[1].erase(0,4);
    cutEntries[1]=cutEntries[1].substr(0,cutEntries[1].length()-1);
    //cutEntries[1].append("g");
    printf("%s ",cutEntries[j].c_str());
}
```

has no sense because you at least cutEntries.size() times are doing

```
    cutEntries[0].erase (0, 6);
    //delete "
    cutEntries[0]=cutEntries[0].substr(0,cutEntries[0].length()-1);
```

This operation should be done outside the loop or you could write for example

```
if ( j == 0 )
{

   cutEntries[j].erase (0, 6);
    //delete "
    cutEntries[j]=cutEntries[j].substr(0,cutEntries[j].length()-1);
}
```

But in any case it is a bad design.

Comment: I wonder why it achieves the goal if it's all wrong!
this loop lopps through all entries and prints them out after cutting the data... anyways, found an approach by using ofStringReplace for everything...

Comment: @suMi Sometimes a wrong code can achieves the goal.:)

Answer (score 0):

this achieves the goal:

```
fullResponse=ofToString(response.data);
//printf("urlResponse %s \n",fullResponse.c_str());
ofStringReplace(fullResponse, "[{", "");
ofStringReplace(fullResponse, "}]", "");
individualEntries=ofSplitString(fullResponse, "},{");
for(int i=0; i<individualEntries.size(); i++){
    printf("entry %s \n",individualEntries[i].c_str());
    vector<string> cutEntries =ofSplitString(individualEntries[i], ",");
    //delete the first parts in all of them
        ofStringReplace(cutEntries[0], "\"ID\":\"", "");
        ofStringReplace(cutEntries[1], "\"path\":\"", "");
        ofStringReplace(cutEntries[2], "\"longitude\":\"", "");
        ofStringReplace(cutEntries[3], "\"latitude\":\"", "");
        ofStringReplace(cutEntries[4], "\"letter\":\"", "");
    //delete the last " in all of them
    ofStringReplace(cutEntries[0], "\"", "");
    ofStringReplace(cutEntries[1], "\"", "");
    ofStringReplace(cutEntries[2], "\"", "");
    ofStringReplace(cutEntries[3], "\"", "");
    ofStringReplace(cutEntries[4], "\"", "");

    for(int j=0; j<cutEntries.size(); j++){
        printf("%s ",cutEntries[j].c_str());
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```